# Javascript - garbage collector timers?

Tags: javascript, browser, garbage-collection

Any idea on garbage collector timer in javascript?
Suppose i run below script, will function and associated scope chained variable will go 
for garbage collection exactly after 100ms? Or some margin?

I read one thread about garbage collection in stackoverflow, still i have this question.
Below are my questions?

1. Does any SYSTEM TIMER run for garbage collection task?
2. If no, is it EVENT based?, means if reference is no more present, garbage 
   collector will reclaim memory INSTANTLY.

   ```
   function call_me() {
   //calculate elapsed_time - code not given

              if(elapsed_time <100)
              {
               setTimeout(call_me,25);
              }
             else{
              final_call();
             }
   }

   call_me();
   ```

Comment: Why does it matter?  The whole point of garbage collection is that it's implicit and not something you really need to worry about.  It's only up to you to make things garbage by dereferencing them from everything else.  What happens after that is likely very implementation specific for each JS engine.

Comment: Garbage collection in JavaScript depends upon the engine used to interpret the code. For example, Rhino uses the JVM. Hence it runs the garbage collector when there are no more references to a certain block of memory. I believe it does so periodically (i.e. it is not event driven). I don't know about other implementations. Garbage collection has nothing to do with JavaScript itself.

Comment: @Praveen: The question is not relevant; by definition, you don't need to worry about the GC.  It is also implementation-specific.

Comment: not relevant to whom? A programmer or who want to know the internal design.

Comment: When you're writing in javascript, as I mentioned in my answer, you have absolutely, 100% no access or control over GC. Indeed, from the perspective of the script, GC does not exist. That is why, in a question about javascript, GC is not relevant. If you were asking a question about programming a user agent, it is quite relevant, but when it comes to javascript, if you can't use it, can't affect it, can't even reference it, then how is it possibly relevant? If your question is about avoiding memory leaks, I'd ask about that instead.

Comment: Sorry @ChrisBaker and others, but I fully agree with the OP that it is absolutely important for the developers to understand how GC works. And you're absolutely wrong in saying that you cannot control it, of course you can, at least to some extent. I invite you to read [this Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management), especially the last sentence of the first paragraph: **gives JavaScript developers the impression they can decide not to care about memory management. This is a mistake.**. The worst thing is an uneducated careless developer.

Comment: @RacilHilan I reviewed the mechanics of GC a little in my answer, but your disagreement here seems misplaced and unfounded.  The document you link does not demonstrate any type of control over GC. You appear to be conflating memory management as a coding practice with garbage collection as a user agent mechanic. There is, simply, no API to control the garbage collector.

Comment: I don't know why my comments was deleted, so here again. The document I linked was not to demonstrate how to control GC, but just to emphasize the importance of knowing who it works. Read the bolded quote in my comment above. And I'm not "conflating memory management with garbage collection", read in the same document **JavaScript utilize a form of automatic memory management known as garbage collection**. As for controlling GC, yes there is no API for that, so you cannot control when it collects (as per the question), but you can control what it collects (by keeping or removing references).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every user agent implements garbage collection differently. All user agents use the [mark-and-sweep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Copying_vs._mark-and-sweep_vs._mark-and-don.27t-sweep) method on a periodic repetition, so there is no "instantly" about it; it will happen when it happens.

Each agent has different thresholds and mechanisms to determine when the GC does a pass. It isn't necessarily event-driven (purhaps you might say it is benchmark-driven, event-initiated), and certainly not based on a timer.

A function that passes out of scope is instantly **eligible** for garbage collection, but there's really no telling when it would happen.

This is really something that, from the developer perspective, you are not intended to think about. There isn't any way to stop or start GC, or any indication that it happened at all. Check out `about:memory` in Firefox for some interesting trivia (and there's a couple of dubious buttons down there to "control" the GC). That's about all you're going to get as far as it goes under the hood, and that data isn't available to scripts.

Comment: Thanks Chris for explanation instead of discouraging someone to ask design specific question. thumbs up :)

Answer (score 3):

The garbage collector is non-deterministic.
Garbage will be collected some time after it becomes garbage.

A closure object passed to `setTimeout` will become garbage after it executes.

Anything beyond that is implementation-specific.