# How does the garbage collector know not to reclaim a callback?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

```
setTimeout(function () {
    alert('Hello');
}, 1000);
```

How does the garbage collector know not to collect the callback function given that `setTimeout` has finished executing? Surely there is no longer a reference to the callback function?

Comment: If there was no reference to it somewhere, how would it ever be called?

Comment: Doesn't this vary by implementation anyway?

Comment: @chepner By a non-standard reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - garbage collector timers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216843/javascript-garbage-collector-timers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The garbage collector determines which objects are reachable from local and global variables and data structures, and those objects are not garbage. In the case of timeout functions, they're reachable from the event queue, a global data structure internal to the Javascript implementation.