# javascript garbage collector not collecting setTimeout()s?

Tags: javascript

I have a function:

```
function test()
{
            for( var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ )
            {
                setTimeout( function()
                {
                    //
                }, 10000 );
            }
}
```

Running this on chrome, it propels memory usage from around 50MB to 600MB, which I guess is ok; but after the timeouts have been executed, the garbage collector doesn't seem to remove them from memory, and it just stays at 600MB until I refresh, even then though it leaves some sort of "foot print" of 150MB after the page refresh.

Any idea how to tell the garbage collector to get rid of them after their execution?

Comment: Propelling memory usage from 50MB to 600MB with that little amount of code is not okay. You're creating a new timer one million times.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8217000/4769440

Comment: Did anyone try this? Does 1M timer really resulting of 600MB usage?

Comment: Made a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ntjhrz6u/1/. In Chrome it didn't go to 600MB, just around 100MB. But it didn't clean itself up even if I waited around 10 seconds.

Comment: What do you mean by "the timeouts"? Do you refer to the callback functions? Did you make a heap snapshot?

Comment: @Barmar Goes to over 500MB for me.

Comment: @Bergi I can give you a screenshot of it if you want.

Comment: @Bergi http://imgur.com/a/rjxGL

Comment: @Daniel_L I don't care about what the taskmanager shows, I believe you that is says that. I wanted to know [whether you investigated the heap](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/), and if not, I ask you to do that to solve your problem.

Comment: @Bergi ah, I see; well, looking at the javascript memory, it doesn't seem to move much, stays at roughly 11,600K (6.900K live).

Comment: But *what* takes up this space? And from where is it retained?

Comment: @Bergi I have no idea, I'll try and play with the memory anaylizing tools some more.

Comment: Hmm, upon further study, the JS heap does go up, from 600 000, to 5 000 000 (donno what that is in), so does do the nodes and listeners, which is how it's supposed to be yes? But it just never gets flushed...

Comment: There are no nodes in the code you've shown us. Are you sure that is what you are testing?

Comment: @Bergi http://imgur.com/a/2WgW6

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that there appears to be memory that is never cleaned up.  <strike>My best guess at the problem is that creating a function in a `for` loop like this creates a new scope which must have access to `i`. Therefore, those functions never get cleaned.</strike> I misspoke - the functions should definitely get cleaned up. Testing in my browser took the memory up over 900MB.

It's important to note that there is no benefit to doing what you are doing and it can be classified as "poor code" at best. You should create one function and reuse it:

```
// reusing a function fixes the problem
function test () {
    var fn = function () {};
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        setTimeout(fn, 1000);
    }
}
```

My observation was that memory usage shot back up over 900MB and then gradually fell back down to closer to normal over the course of a couple minutes.

If you are needing access to the variable `i` inside of your functions, I hate to say that your code will not give you that. You will only ever see the *last value of `i` (1000000)*. If you are wanting to use `i` inside your functions, you can use a factory function. In my tests the memory eventually got cleaned up:

```
// using a factory fixes the problem and give you access to 'i'
function test () {
    function factory (n) {
        return function () {
            /* This will get called later. 'n' will represent
               the value of 'i' at the time this function was created */
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        setTimeout(factory(i), 1000);
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, the memory problem persists if you use `bind`:

```
// Memory problem still exists with .bind
function test () {
    var fn = function (n) { };
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        setTimeout(fn.bind(null, i), 1000);
    }
}
```

As for the memory usage remaining high after a page refresh, this I cannot explain but it might have to do with the browser setting aside more memory for a tab which appears to be using a lot of memory. I dunno, just a guess.

Comment: "*Therefore, those functions never get cleaned*" - I don't follow. After each function was called and had its scope created, there's nothing to hold onto?

Comment: Well this is confusing, apparentely if I use "setTimeout(fn, 1000);" then it works, but if I use "setTimeout( fn, 1000 );" then it doesn't work?

Comment: @bergi - Thanks - I was looking at the problem wrong. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @DmytroLysak - I'm not sure what you mean. Having spaces inside your setTimeout call causes memory issues? I have a hard time believing that. Can you make a fiddle.

Comment: @RyanWheale nvm, I can't seem to replicate them on jsFiddle.

Comment: What is a factory thing you are using? And why are there brackets outside the test() function?

Comment: Sorry, that was code that shouldn't have been in there. I updated my answer. A "factory" function is used to build another function. In this case, we build a new function on each iteration of the loop. Each function that we build has access to their own unique value of `i`.

Comment: @RyanWheale ah, I see. I tried that factory function method, but it doesn't seem to clear the memory, still stays over 400MB.